# Selenium IDE - plugin to find alternate ID selectors?

Tags: css, plugins, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm using extjs, so often I need the parent's ID, or the parent's parent's ID for a selector. Is there any plugin which lets me traverse up a DOM element looking for different IDs, or a plugin which can filter out certain ID patterns? (such as `ext-gen\d+`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution. Use CSS selectors manually and make sure you're running on `>FF3.x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) plugin for Firefox to find the IDs

Comment: Of course I can use firebug. The goal is to get selenium-IDE able to pick up the right selectors, or else the point of the tool is somewhat lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to use XPath - it can search even element which contains something. See one of examples here: http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example6.html

I believe you can set the IDE to search by XPath and not only by ID

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is unique identification of the element. Xpath works better with FF,Safari and Chrome. But it breaks in IE sometime, so in that case you can use Css selectors.You can use Firebug. Over Firebug you need to install firepath. 
You dont have to consider the DOM before using XPATH generated by firepath. It is very useful if you are having the elements that have dynamic IDs.
Both Firebug and firepath are the mozilla addons.
First install Firebug then firepath.

In the Selenium IDE when you are recording something. There is drop-down menu in **Target** in that select XPath:Position. It will work for dynamic element and does not change.

Cheers, 
Amit Shakya